# Does Stopping a Bitlocker Encryption Process Damage Harddrives or Data?

Tags: windows, disk-encryption, windows-10, bitlocker

I've started Bitlocker Encryption on a pretty large internal drive around 4TB, it's obviously a stupid mistake from my side. It's been running for a long time. What will happen if I cancel it which I'll never do.

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel it, it’ll just reverse the process.

Note: you’re free to shutdown the computer during this process.  The encryption process will resume upon next reboot.  It’ll even recover from a power failure.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ee449438(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#what-happens-if-the-computer-is-turned-off-during-encryption-or-decryption

> What happens if the computer is turned off during encryption or decryption?
> If the computer is turned off or goes into hibernation, the BitLocker encryption and decryption process will resume where it stopped the next time Windows starts. This is true even if the power is suddenly unavailable